# Canada Conference : Proof of Funding

Tags: visas, canada, proof-provenance-of-funds, business-travel, nigerian-citizens

I am attending a conference in Canada in September. My employer is sponsoring the trip for everything (Hotel, Cash, Airline tickets etc.) Do i need to make available the bank statement of my employer or is it enough to have a letter from my employer detailing that they would be responsible for the payment for the trip etc.

Because I am from Nigeria I expect it's important to have all my documentation perfect.

Answer (score 1):

A letter from your employer is sufficient, provided that it identifies you and states specifically which expenses the company will cover. For instance it's not sufficient to say something like "all expenses", instead it should say something like "hotel, airfare, and per diem".

Comment: If the organization is an unknown 5 person company, he definitely needs to add a bank statement from the outfit. If it’s a Microsoft or Bank of Nigeria or IBM, then no need to.